# Validity period for SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have ssrs 2008 r2 rdls. I open an SSRS report and keep it open in my browser for more than 30 mins. If I now click any drill downs either through an action or goto report. I don't want the report get me that info. It should state that the report is expired.

Is there a solution already available . Do future version SQL server have a solution for this.

Comment: It is unclear from your use of acronyms and this brief explanation what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Take the time to explain your problem and results as clearly as possible, formatting the text to make it clear what you are doing. If you cannot provide a [mcve] perhaps you need to research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Clarification of questions should be in the question itself. [Edit] the question and make it clear in the text what you want to do, what you have tried with your [mcve] and what results you got, including any error messages. From your comments, this looks like it isn't about coding, so it is probably off-topic for [SO].

Comment: @jdv - the OP wants the SSRS report links to not work if the report has been opened for more than 30 minutes. If you don't know the product, maybe you shouldn't comment. Most devs know the MCVE is lame - most stackoverflow questions don't have it.

Comment: @HannoverFist you seem to be an expert so why are you putting a potential answer in a comment? Or, maybe, you could edit the question to make it more clear what is actually being asked here. Either way, comments are not for answers or complaining; they are for clarifying and improving Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

There not a built in way to do this natively in SSRS.

I haven't heard of anyone asking about a requirement like this before so I doubt that there's something already in the works to add it.

I don't know JavaScript enough to know whether or not you can add logic to the JavaScript URL to where it would create a blank link or link to a Page Expired page.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://na5.salesforce.com/','_blank'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden datetime parameter on the main report and set its default value to the current time: `=Now()`. Let's call this parameter `@MainReportRuntime`.

Make this same hidden parameter on your subreports and pass `@MainReportRuntime` through to the subreports.

Modify the SQL of the subreport to only return data when the date is within half an hour of the main report runtime and add the report expiry message when it is greater than half an hour old:

```
SELECT SomeField
FROM SomeTable
WHERE @MainReportRuntime >= DateAdd(mi, -30, Current_Timestamp) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Report has expired - please rerun report to get current data'
WHERE @MainReportRuntime < DateAdd(mi, -30, Current_Timestamp)
```